# Is it possible to have shared tasks for different environments (stages) on VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have release pipeline in VSTS that has four stages. Dev, Test, Pre-Prod and Prod. These stages share the same steps and the only difference are the variable values that change depending of the stage.

At the moment if I add a new step I have to add it on the four stages even if it is the same and the only difference is the value of the variables.

Is it possible to have a shared stage that is used by my four environments where the only difference would be the variables. This is to prevent having to add the same step four times

Comment: I've been copy and pasting the environments but with variables so I'd be interested in a solution to this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [task groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/library/task-groups?view=vsts). Task groups allow you to define a set of build/release steps and reuse them across different builds, releases, and release environments.

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was looking for